# Finding the differential of a thrice differentiable function

Tags: derivatives, continuity, differential

Let f : R→R be a non-constant , three times differentiable function. If  f(1+1/n)=1 for all integers , then f''(1) equals?
I don't even know how to start this problem!

Comment: Taylor's theorem

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Can you start by finding $f'(1)$ by using the sequence $1+1/n\to 1$ ($n\to\infty$)? Now consider either the second-order Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $1$ or  a formula for $f''(a)$ using $a+h$, $a$, and $a-h$.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need $f$ to be three-times differentiable.